# ActiveMQ durable consumer retains its subscription after topic was deleted

Tags: java, c#, activemq-classic, nms

If topic was deleted while durable consumer was offline it's subscription will remain.

Next time after `ISession.CreateDurableConsumer` is called the consumer will receive the same old subscription (as I understand), and no messages from newly created topic. No new messages are sent to this particular subscriber at all.

The only way start to receive messages is to delete this durable consumer and create a new one.

Questions:

1. Is it ActiveMQ's normal behavior?
2. How to know that consumers subscription was broken while it was offline and it needs to resubscribe?

I'm using ActiveMQ 5.15.10 and Apache.NMS.ActiveMQ

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "topic was deleted"? How was it deleted?

Comment: @JustinBertram Hi! It was deleted using button "delete" in tab "Topics" in Apache ActiveMQ Console